# Android ViewModel observer does not work? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Inside the fragment of a tabbed activity:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    serverSetVM = ViewModelProvider(activity!!).get(ServersViewModel::class.java)

    serverList = ArrayList(serverSetVM.get())
    rv = rv_serverList // findViewById 
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    rv.adapter = ServerListRevAdapter(context!! ,serverList) 

    serverSetVM.serverSetLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  Observer {

        Log.v ("MainAct", "Inside OBSERVER")
        serverList = ArrayList(serverSetVM.get())
        rv.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

Also;

```
val serverSetLiveData = MutableLiveData<HashSet<Server>>() // Inside ViewModel class
```

`observe()` function does not seem to work. When the value of `ServerSetVM` is modified inside the same fragment (by the functions defined in ViewModel class, i.e. `add()`), recyclerView is not updated. According to Logcat output, `Observer` lambda is called only after `onCreateView()`.

I confirmed MutableLiveData gets updated but `Observer{}` lambda is not called. Do I need to correct my notion about ViewModels?

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**
Use " = " operator to modify the MutableLiveData value so that observer can detect it. Even `serverSetLiveData.value=serverSetLiveData.value` does the job.

Comment: This only works if `serverSetVM` is mutable list, which it shouldn't have to be. Should be using `adapter.setItems(list)` or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "Should be using `adapter.setItems(list)` or something like that" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Observer only observe if you call setValue() or postValue() method of MutableLiveData**

where you are calling the setValue() or postValue() function for serverSetLiveData .
eg. serverSetLiveData.setValue(serverList) or serverSetLiveData.postValue(serverList). in the code.

Comment: `ServerSetVM.add()` inside the fragment calls `serverSetLiveData.value!!.add()` inside the ViewModel class. Since there is no `setValue()` or `postValue()` method in Kotlin maybe I should update `serverSetLiveData.value` by the "=" operator instead of `add()`.

Comment: Yes kotlin replace setValue() and getValue() with value. if you use like serverSetLiveData.value=serverList. Means you are using setValue() and if you use like serverSetLiveData.value. Means you are using getValue(). yes postValue() function exist in kotlin

Comment: to use livedata you must use `livedata.value` or `livedata.postValue()` in viewModel(), include when some update with your list. live data will not trigger when you just do "livedata.value.list.add('new Item)", you must set value for live data to trigger it.
`livedata.value = newList` something like that.

Comment: @Black4Guy Thank you. "="  operator worked. Would be nice if you edit your answer for Kotlin and I accept it. Btw, even though I get inside the `Observer` Lambda, recyclerView adapter is not updated. Why do you think?

Comment: `setValue` in Java is the same as `.value =` in Kotlin, see the interop guide on property accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Obervre gets triggered only if you call `.value =`